# Arch Linux startx on login

Tags: login, arch-linux, user

I want to start my window manager when I log in with a spesiific user, but stay in the console if I log in as root. So I want the startup to be as it is, but at the login prompt, if I choose my user, it automaticly runs '$ startx' basicly, while if I log in as root, nothing happens.
Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While I'd just use a display manager (I use LXDM set to automatically login to my user) and switch to the console when I need to be root, you might want to try [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Start_X_at_Login) (from the Arch wiki):

> For Bash, add the following to the bottom of `~/.bash_profile`. If the file does not exist, copy a skeleton version from `/etc/skel/.bash_profile`
>
> For Zsh, add it to `~/.zprofile` instead.

```
[[ -z $DISPLAY && $XDG_VTNR -eq 1 ]] && exec startx
```